# In MySQL (5.1) what is best way to detect one set of columns is not equal to another

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I have two tables a source and a destination.  I want to flag the destination table to be updated if any of the corresponding columns in source columns are different.  The columns can be null.

Currently this seems very clumsy:

```
UPDATE destination d
JOIN source s
   ON d.id = s.id
SET d.updateFlag = 1
WHERE (    (d.col1 IS NULL AND s.col1 IS NOT NULL) 
        OR (d.col1 IS NOT NULL AND s.col1 IS NULL)
        OR (d.col1 <> s.col1)
      )
      OR
      (    (d.col2 IS NULL AND s.col2 IS NOT NULL) 
        OR (d.col2 IS NOT NULL AND s.col2 IS NULL)
        OR (d.col2 <> s.col2)
      )
      ...etc...
      OR
      (    (d.colN IS NULL AND s.colN IS NOT NULL) 
        OR (d.colN IS NOT NULL AND s.colN IS NULL)
        OR (d.colN <> s.colN)
      )
```

Ideally I could do something like:

```
UPDATE destination d
JOIN source s
   ON d.id = s.id
SET d.updateFlag = 1
WHERE HASH(d.col1,d.col2,...etc...,d.colN) <> HASH(s.col1,s.col2,...etc...,s.colN)
```

Some additional info.  The columns are all different data types (some ints, some bits, some strings) and we are using a flavor of MySQL 5.1.

Comment: This doesn't quite qualify as an answer (and I hope your question has an elegant answer, because it seems like it should): you could [`CRC32()`](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=191) each column and add the results, then check if the huge number you get is equal. I'm not proud of the idea but I thought it was worth a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your statement by using the [NULL-safe equal to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator:

```
UPDATE destination d
JOIN source s
   ON d.id = s.id
SET d.updateFlag = 1
WHERE !(d.col1 <=> s.col1)
   OR !(d.col2 <=> s.col2)
...etc
```

As an alternative, you can use a UNION to find duplicate rows:

```
  SELECT tbl, id, col1, col2, col3
    FROM (
  SELECT 't1' AS tbl, id, col1, col2, col3
    FROM t1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 't2' AS tbl, id, col1, col2, col3
    FROM t2
       ) tmp
GROUP BY id, col1, col2, col3 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

You can then use the result from that in your update query:

```
UPDATE destination d
   SET d.updateFlag = 1
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM (
        SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM t1
        UNION All
        SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM t2
     ) tmp
     WHERE d.id = tmp.id
  GROUP BY id, col1, col2, col3
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html), which is one of the tools in [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/).  This does what you're describing, calculating a checksum for the entire row and comparing it to the corresponding row in another database.

Many people use this tool to verify that a slave is a true replica of its master, but you can compare any two databases that have similar metadata.